How to get the Append blob type files and delete those files
I am working on a project where I need to retrieve and delete Append blob files stored in Azure Blob Storage using .Net Core. I've been able to work with Block blobs using the Azure Storage SDK, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle Append blobs.
Could someone provide me with a .Net Core code snippet or point me to some documentation that demonstrates how to list all Append blob files in a container and then delete them?
I appreciate any help or guidance you can provide. Thank you!

Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written so far (you mentioned that you are able to work with block blobs).


How to get the Append blob type files and delete those files

This worked for me.
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            try
            {
                string container_name = "test";
                string conn = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";  //connection string


                BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(conn);

                BlobContainerClient container_client = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container_name);

                var blobs = container_client.GetBlobsAsync();


                await foreach (BlobItem blob in blobs)
                {

                    BlobClient blob_client = container_client.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
                    var blob_properties = await blob_client.GetPropertiesAsync();
                    if (blob_properties.Value.BlobType == BlobType.Append)
                    {
                        await blob_client.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Deleted file; {blob.Name}");
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

OUTPUT:
append.txt is a append type blob in the list:

It got deleted:


